# mysql - determine stoppages at a particular location

Tags: mysql, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I have a mysql table as follows(5 coloumns):

> id |Vehicle_no |Time                 | latitude    |Longitude
>
> 1  |Abc123     |2015-09-15 20:15:51 |  26.211718   | 86.877197
>
> 2  |Abc123     |2015-09-15 20:16:51 |  26.211718   | 86.877197
>
> 3  |Abc123     |2015-09-15 20:17:51 |  26.211718   | 86.877197
>
> 4  |Abc123     |2015-09-15 20:18:51 |  26.211718   | 86.877197
>
> 5  |Abc123     |2015-09-15 20:19:51 |  26.211718   | 86.877197
>
> 6  |Abc123     |2015-09-15 20:20:51 |  26.212718   | 86.878197
>
> 7  |Abc123     |2015-09-15 20:21:51 |  26.212728   | 86.878200
>
> 8  |Abc123     |2015-09-15 20:22:51 |  26.212738   | 86.877201

The above values I am getting from a GPS receiver every minute. If the latitude and longitude remains same say for e.g more than 5 minutes at a particular day I must indicate that the vehicle is stationary at this location (lat. and long.) on this particular date. In table for id. no 6, 7 there is different lat. and long which means vehicle is moving.
The values of lat. and long may be repeated because I am crossing the same route everyday(same lat. and long.) but the time and date may be different.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: if it is stationary for more than 5 minutes i want to pass on as json so that i can indicate on google map marker as stationary for xxx time

Comment: 6 decimal places = 16cm or 6 inches.  If the GPS receiver is recomputing every minute, I suspect it will often claim that you have moved when you have not.  Any solution really needs to include a tolerance to say "close" is "not moving".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id, 1 as is_stationary from positions p
where not exists (select 0 from positions pp
    where p.time > pp.time
    and datediff(p.time, pp.time) <= 5/(60*24)
     and p.latitude <> pp.latitude
     and p.longitude <> pp.longitude)
```

I don't know what you want to do with the result -- write it to a new column or whatever -- so consider stuff up through "from" on the first line as a dummy placeholder.

Comment: query not clear.can it be elaborated ,please. thanks

Comment: I edited it.  The idea is that it returns stationary rows by finding those which lack a different location in the last five minutes.

Comment: thanks paul. can it be more refined for selecting records with today's date only. the above query returns all previous records.

Comment: >  thanks @paulKienitz . modified the query and now works like charm       >  SELECT id, vehicle_no,latitude, longitude,time, count(id) as cnt             >   FROM positions GROUP BY lat,lng HAVING cnt > 5 and time like 'theDaterequired%'order by id desc